# Purpose of the C++ keyword: &= (a.k.a. 'and_eq')

Tags: c++, keyword

Neither [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/and_eq) nor [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ciso646/), and nor [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/and-eq?view=vs-2019) websites provided the verbose definition of the C++ keyword **&=** (a.k.a. **and_eq**), despite examples that seem to be a bit cryptic for a novice.

Yet the book `C++ In a Nutshell: A Desktop Quick Reference` by `Lischner` provided the [following](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Q4iP1mkfdtsC&pg=PT307&lpg=PT307&dq=and_eq%20c%2B%2B&source=bl&ots=w-l8dAWW8q&sig=ACfU3U0nfNgsJPG5eUKx87Tm1iffINxnyQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjczICNi-ThAhV6VBUIHXi1DJI4ChDoATABegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=and_eq%20c%2B%2B&f=false) (p. 291, 2003):

> The and_eq operator is an assignment operator that performs bitwise and.

Quoting the example from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/and-eq?view=vs-2019):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iso646.h>

int main( )
{
   using namespace std;
   int a = 3, b = 2, result;
   result= a &= b;
   cout << result << endl;
}
```

yields `2`.

Accordingly, could you please tell me whether **&=** is a shortcut for concatenated assignments (if such a thing exists?), for example: `result = a = b;`?

Comment: `&=` is discussed on cppreference.com in the section on [Assignment Operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment). It is the "bitwise AND assignment" operator, see the section on "Builtin compound assignment" on that same page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&=`, and all of the other `op=` built in operators are described in [[expr.ass]\7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.ass#7) as

> The behavior of an expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = E1 op E2`except that `E1` is evaluated only once. In `+=` and `-=`, `E1` shall either have arithmetic type or be a pointer to a possibly cv-qualified completely-defined object type. In all other cases, `E1` shall have arithmetic type.

So, `result= a &= b;` is the same as

```
result = (a = (a & b));
```

or textually:

> store the result of bitwise and between a and b into a and result.

Answer (score 4):

No. `a &= b` is a shortcut for `a = a & b`.

Additionally, `a = b` returns the value that was assigned to `a`. So `result = a &= b` is short for:

```
a = a & b;
result = a;
```

Comment: Unless `operator &=` has been overloaded for the type of `a` ;-) The type is `int` here, so it can't have been overloaded. But for non built-in types, it could have.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a keyword, it's an expression operator. Found here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions

It is the bit-wise AND operator combined with the assignment operator. On primitive types, it performs a bit-wise AND on the two parameters and then assigns the result to the first parameter.

```
uint32_t a = 0b00110101;
uint32_t b = 0b01101011;

a &= b;
//Equivalent: a = a & b;
assert(a == 0b00100001);
```

Comment: So, and_eq is a keyword, and &= is an operator considering the following: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/and_eq ?

Comment: @KutalmisB `and_eq` is a keyword, `&=` is an operator.

Answer (score 2):

`foo &= bar` is short for `foo = foo & bar`, for built-in types. *But*, it's an operator that can be reimplemented by user defined types, so it's semantics *could* be changed for such.

Answer (score 1):

There’s one relevant difference between `a = a & b;` and `a &= b;`.  The former creates a temporary equal to `a & b` and assigns that temporary value to `a`.  The latter updates `a` in place.

For built-in types, that doesn’t matter: any compiler will just optimize either expression to the same machine-language instruction.  If you define a class and overload the operators, though, writing `a = a & b;` might end up creating a temporary object, copying a bunch of data to it, and then copying all its data somewhere else.  While there are ways to mitigate this problem, `a &= b;` is in theory more efficient.